# Плагин Uploadify для jQuery

Tags: jquery

Привет всем.

Такой вопросик будет....
Как можно другой вид при загрузки файлов с помощью данного плагина? Т.е. мне например нужно отображать свой красивый прогресс-бар подходящий под дизайн сайта. Куда мне лезть? Устанавливать Flash и редактировать .FLA как я хочу? Или есть более простой способ это сделать?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по демонстрации на сайте, чтобы изменить вид полосы загрузки во flash лезть не нужно. За это отвечает файл jquery.uploadify именно он формирует блок. А стили подтягиваются из цсс uploadify.css. Именно стили Вам нужно изменять чтобы стилизировать полосу загрузки и ее контейнер под свой сайт. А если хотите изменить работу блока, например увеличить или уменьшить время появления/исчезновения, тогда изменяйте яваскрипт.